# Visual Studio: Export C# Code into a PDF file and keep the formatting + colors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf

I was wondering if there is any export function inside `Visual Studio Ultimate (2010)` to get a chosen `tab` (by default a single `class`) of `C# code` exported into a `PDF` file, so you can share that PDF file and show someone the code, with the formatting and colors of Visual Studio? I'm sending the PDF with sample code for an application, that's how I came to this question.

I know that I could copy the code into Word in a textbox, that works fine and keeps colors + formatting. I am just interested if there is an option in Visual Studio too? It's not important, just want to know. ;-)

Comment: Just print into a virtual printer that generates PDFs

Comment: Yes that's a good idea, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com). Just install it, and go to file->print in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to do this myself so google brought me here.  Then I had a mini brainwave and remembered "Microsoft Print to PDF" which is built in as an option in the print menu.  I tried it and it worked!

So just go File->Print, then choose `Microsoft Print to PDF` as the printer, then choose where to save your printout.[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a *PDF printer* tool like:

- [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) (PDF Reader and printer)
- [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) (PDF printer only)

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 but colors were not printing.

If you are using **Visual Studio 2010-2012**, you might want to check the following extension from Microsoft: [Color Printing](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44/?SRC=Home)

If you are using **Visual Studio 2013**, you can check this extension from Microsoft which includes color printing: [Productivity Power Tools 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace)

If you are using **Visual Studio 2015**, you can check this extension from Microsoft which includes color printing: [Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)

Answer (score 0):

You can use VscodePrint extension. Google 'VScodePrint' and try it. You can print or exports to PDF any part of a Solution.